# How to increase RabbitMQ file descripter limit in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

We are very close to the limit of 1024 (as advertised in the rabbitmq admin)

I assume 1024 is the limit for user rabbitmq. How do we increase the limit on ubuntu to increase this to some arbitrary number, say 64000 for user rabbitmq.

Comment: When I first started using rabbitmq, I kept hitting the file descripter limit because I was opening new connections when opening a channel would [suffice](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) (which, incidently, is also faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) shows how to check the number of file descripters and also change them on linux. On ubuntu instead of su'ing to root you can use sudo.